# Foundation for sites: min width / fixed table column

Tags: css, html-table, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to solve this problem using the Foundation's (for sites, 6.3.0 version) classes.

I have to show a table with a lot of data (and columns), and I want 2 of them to have a minimal width, so that the content (which have fixed length) does not wrap.

I tried setting the `min-width` of the `td` and `th` elements, without luck.

If there is no way to do with Foundation, I will simply code my own CSS table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using a little CSS trick, maybe it's widely know, but for those like me I'll explain:

I've simply added a class for the `td` like this:

```
td.min {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will set the `td` width to fit the content, without wrapping it.